# Issues Reading a CSV file into a C Struct

Tags: c, csv, struct

I've just started learning C, and I'm currently trying to create a program to automate a fishing minigame I made for my D&D campaign. In order to do so, I created a CSV containing all the tables I had originally written up. I've been trying a variety of things for about a week now to just simply read the CSV into C so that I can call specific elements at will. I've finally gotten something to very nearly work, but I'm getting a strange problem. Firstly, the CSV is formatted as such:

```
bluefish,str,2,5
bluefish,str,2,5
bluefish,str,2,5
bluefish,str,2,5
kahawai,dex,2,1000
narrow barred mackerel,str,3,5
```

It goes on for another 400 lines, but you get the point. My current code looks like the following:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[50];
    char contest[5];
    int modifier;
    int value;
} fts_t;




    /*Checking for the file and opening it*/
    FILE *tpointer;

    tpointer = fopen("fishing_tables.csv", "r");
    printf("Accessing Fishing Tables...\n");

    if(tpointer == NULL){
        
        printf("Error: Missing fishing_tables.csv");
        return 0;

    } else{

        printf("Success! Importing Data...\n");

    }

    
    /*Creating a struct array and initializing variables*/
    fts_t ft[400];
    char buffer[1024];
    int count = 0;
    char name[100];
    char contest[3];
    int modifier;
    int value;

    while(fgets(buffer, 1024, tpointer)){
        sscanf(buffer, " %[^,],%[^,],%d,%d", name, contest, &modifier, &value);
        strcpy(ft[count].name, name);
        strcpy(ft[count].contest, contest);
        ft[count].modifier = modifier;
        ft[count].value = value;
        printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n", ft[count].name, ft[count].contest, ft[count].modifier, ft[count].value);
        count++;
    }
```

So, following above, I'm having it print out the elements of the struct at each count as it loops, just to check that it's creating the struct correctly. The problem comes in that the output looks like this:

```
        dex     2       15

        dex     2       15

        dex     2       15

        dex     2       15

        dex     2       15

next    0       0       0

next    0       0       0

next    0       0       0

next    0       0       0

next    0       0       0
```

Now, hilariously, the rows beginning with "next" are the only rows printing correctly. I have these added in for some extra shenanigans in the context of the minigame, but what's important is that those are correct. However, in every other row, the name variable is not being read, and I'm really lost as to why, when the "next" rows are functioning fine. I've checked the actual variable itself, and it appears there's some sort of problem in my sscanf statement.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A very good start would be to check the return value of `sscanf`.

Comment: `char contest[3]` Strings in C are NUL terminated. That means a three letter word like `str` requires a four byte array to store. Overflowing buffers results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: You showed some sample data — thank you.  But your sample output, some of which is correct and some of which is not, bears no relation to the sample data.  That makes it hard for us to help debug the code.  Also, it would be best if your sample data was at least somewhat different in each row — spotting the difference between the first 4 sample rows is difficult, and that can hide a variety of problems.  Please show the code with a minimal `main()` and show sample data that gives the problem.

Comment: I increased the string size and it now reads perfectly. Thanks so much kaylum!